# Worldpay Notification on Mobile

Tags: android, ios, rest, paypal-ipn, worldpay

Looking at the [Paypal SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md), I can see how it would be easy to integrate Paypal into a mobile app and receive notification of payment using the REST services that it provides. This is ideal because I can make in-app changes based on the payment information that is returned.

However, Worldpay offer lower fee's, so I would prefer to integrate worldpay into my IPhone and Android apps. I looked [here](http://www.worldpay.com/support/bg/index.php?page=guides&c=UK) for the 'Payment Notification' system that worldpay offers, but it only seems to be capable of sending a single response to a server. In this case I would probably have to implement a push notification system (which would be sent on the notification coming into the server) to the phone that originally requested the data, which seems a bit long winded.

Are the same callbacks possible using Worldpay as they are in the above link to the Paypal SDK? Is it viable to use Worldpay in this way on a mobile platorm?

Thanks,
Jo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get WorldPay to send both a POST message to your server, and an email to the customer.

Both are documented [here](http://support.worldpay.com/support/kb/bg/paymentresponse/payment_response.html). The first is set up on the WorldPay server (and so the destination script is fixed) and the second is requested by the mobile app’s connection to WorldPay.

Comment: Worldpay offers several *merchant channels* like email, shopper email, http. You can configure the http channel to use either CGI or XML via GET or POST. There are a lot of events (AUTHORISED, REFUSED, CANCELLE, DEXPIRED, ...) and for each channel you can individually activate any event for which you want a notification.